# Are the integrals uniformly continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: integration, analysis, derivatives, uniform-continuity

I want to check if one of the following is uniformly continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

1. $\int_0^{x^3}\sin t\, dt$
2. $\int_0^x\cos (t^3)\, dt$
3. $\int_0^x[t]\, dt$
4. $\int_0^xe^{t^3}\, dt$

To  check that do we have to check if the derivative is Lipschitz continuous?

If yes I suppose that teh second one satisfies that property, since the cosine function is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer for 2) is correct.

For 1) note that the function is just $1-\cos (x^{3})$. Can you show that this is not uniformly continuous?  [Consider the points $(2n\pi)^{1/3}$ and $(2n\pi+\frac {\pi} 2)^{1/3}$.

For 3)use the fact that you can compute the integral explicitly by splitting the integral into $0$ to $1$, $1$ to $2$ etc. Now check that the values at $n$ and $n+\frac 1 n$ difer by $1$ which shows that the function is not uniformly continuous. I will leave differentiabilty to you.

For 4) here is  a hint: $0<x<y$ implies $\int_x^{y} e^{t^{2}} dt \geq e^{x^{2}} (y-x)$. Choose $x$ and $y$ appropriately to contradict uniformly continuity.

Comment: So at 1) we take limit $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$ and check if the result is finite?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, the limit is $\frac {\pi} 2$.

Comment: So does it hold that $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx=\int_0^{\infty}\sin x\, dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$ ?

Comment: That is a well know fact from Calculus. @MaryStar

Comment: So that means that the first integral is uniformly continuous? And it is also differentiable from fundamental calculus, or not?

Comment: The functions in 1), 2) and 4) are differentiable by FTC.  Since the integral in 3) can be computed explicitly I am leaving differentiabilty to you. @MaryStar

Comment: As for 1) according to Wolfram at infinity the result is not finite : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E%28infty%29%28sinx%29dx That means that this integral is not uniform continuous, right?

Comment: @MaryStar I read the first part wrongly. I have now corrected the answer.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)